# LIBSVM 'decision values' in C# LibSVMsharp library

Tags: c#, libsvm

It's my understanding that when training an SVM on the command line you can specify a -b parameter with -b 0 (default) or -b 1 to enable 'decision values' or 'probability estimates' respectively. I'm using LIBSVM with a C-SVC based multi-class problem with 5 classes. I can obtain probability estimates in the C# library using

```
testset.PredictProbability(model, out estimations);
```

After the prediction, I can see the 5 probability estimates within the 'estimations' output object. It's my understanding that there should be 10 decision values for the 5 class model i.e. one for class 1 vs class 2, another for class 1 vs class 3 and so forth. How do I get the 'decision values'?

Answer (score 0):

There are three predict functions exposed through the libsvm API. Predict, predict with probabilities and predict with values. There is currently no way to obtain both the probability estimates and decision values simultaneously.

The decision values can be returned by calling the *PredictValues* function. They will indeed be in the form of class X vs class Y for classification, as multi-class SVM is performed through an one-vs-one approach. This causes k*(k-1)/2 classifiers to be trained (one separating each pair of classes). These are the raw decision values used by SVM. The probabilities on the other hand is an *estimated* probability for each class, and will therefore of course only consist of a single value per class.